# Rufus and Diskpart for clean install - some confusion

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, diskpart, rufus

Any help to clarify appreciated!
Am planning to use diskpart access from the command line in my Rufus boot USB as a first step to clean and format my destination drive.
Plan on using these commands

```
clean
create part pri
active
format fs=ntfs label = 512Windows quick
```

1st question> SInce this will be my Startup or C drive do I need to use a label? ie C,D,etc

Next will reboot again into my Rufus USB to do a clean install of Windows

2nd question
SInce I've already formatted the drive I assume I skip and formatting options and just install?

Question 3
Knowing the above how do I configure my Rufus USB at the very beginning?

Question 4
Is there any advantage in choosing the dual UEFI + Legacy option (alt+E) ?

Question 5
If I choose UEFI nonCSM in Rufus, does this mean that I MUST have CSM disabled in my actual UEFI-BIOS?

Question 6
Partitioning Scheme and Target System apply to the destination drive for the Windows install but the formatting options refer to the actual USB media and NOT the destination windows 10 drive.
Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: Unless you have special requirements you should not be creating partitions manually before installing. // Please don’t mix topics. There’s two here: How to prepare your boot drive, and how to use Rufus.

Comment: You shouldn't have to prepare your system disk to install Windows.  If you are then you are either dual booting (which you made no mention of) or preparing the disk unnecessarily and likely incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks. Already tried forgoing disk prep but was getting errors like incompatible partition scheme etc.

The bigger issue is that this drive was part of a dual boot setup with linux on another dive and for some reason I don't recall, think I had a MBR paritioning scheme on the Windows drive.
Hence the need to clean it entirely. Not converned about dual boot for nw. Juts need Windows.

Comment: Rufus will do all that for you automatically.

Comment: Well actually it doesn’t, because Rufus is not involved with any of that. That’s why mixing topics in questions is bad. // I once again _strongly_ recommend splitting this question.